# Set Tab Color Based on Offset from Column

Tags: excel, vba

I have an index of tabs in my workbook. Before I found out that you could color the cells based on the tabs, I did them manually, and now need to color the tabs based on the cells (offset by 3 cols)

I've tried a few different way of doing it, nothing works, or even happens to give pointers from.

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim Ki As Range
    Dim ListSh As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Prior Data")

ws.Activate

    With ws
        Set ListSh = .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
    End With

ws2.Activate

On Error Resume Next
For Each Ki In ListSh
    Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Ki.Value)
    ws3.Tab.Color = ws2.Range("A2:A").Find(Ki.Value).Offset(0, 3).Interior.Color
Next Ki
```

I'm basically hoping that the tabs match the tags next to their name in the index[image]

Comment: Delete `On Error Resume Next` and then execute your code and see if any error arises. `On Error Resume Next` does not prevent erros from ocurring, just hides them.

Comment: `ws2.Range("A2:A").Find(Ki.Value).Offset(0, 3).Interior.Color` Where is the End Row in Col A ;)  or do `ws2.Columns(1)`. But then do not use `On Error Resume Next`. Handle it properly as shown [HERE](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
Dim MyPos As Long
For Each Ki In ListSh
    Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Ki.Value)
    MyPos = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Ki.Value, ws2.Range("A:A"), 0)
    ws3.Tab.Color = ws2.Range("D" & MyPos).Interior.Color
Next Ki
```

With `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Ki.Value, ws2.Range("A:A"), 0)` you can find the row number that holds the `Ki.Value`. Then get the color from same row but column D.

**NOTE:** If `WorksheetFunction.Match` does not find any match, it will throw an error, so you'll need to handle it.

Comment: That works almost perfectly, and for the 0.5% that's not working I can do fix them manualy